# How to get product review rating value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the review rating value by name for storing a value in a database. I am using [this library](https://github.com/glix/j-plugin/tree/master/Simple-jQuery-Star-Rating-System-For-Bootstrap-3) for the review rating control. I can't  find out a way to get the name value. My code markup is

```
<input name="rating-id" type="text" id="rating-id" class="rating-kv" min=0 max=5 step=0.2 data-size="sm">
```

```js
$('#rating-id').rating().on('rating.change', function(event, value, caption) {
    $("#rating-id").value;
});
```

Is there way to get it's name value while changing review rating or is there a better review rating plugin for use.

Comment: As per the docs you linked to, it's the `value` argument provided to the handler function: https://github.com/glix/j-plugin/tree/master/Simple-jQuery-Star-Rating-System-For-Bootstrap-3#ratingchange

Comment: jQuery syntax is `$("#rating-id").val()` or `this.value`

Comment: not working,  @mplungjan

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, how to get name value

Comment: Assuming you mean the `name` attribute of the element, `$(this).prop('name')` or `this.name`

Comment: If `this` doesn't work in the above examples, try `$(event.target).prop('name')` or `event.target.name`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, i tried with both   $('#rating-id').rating().on('rating.change', function(event, value, caption) {
    $(event.target).prop('name'); 
}); and   $('#rating-id').rating().on('rating.change', function(event, value, caption) {
    $(event.target).prop('name').val();
}); but not working :(

Comment: @NayeemHyderRiddhi please let me know what is name value?

Comment: @AswinKumar, <input name="rating-id"

Comment: Can you give better review rating plugin, if it don't work

Comment: `rating:change` is a valid event name from the [doc:events](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating#events) you've `rating` `.` `change`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `change` event.

Note the plugin events `rating.change`, `rating.clear` and `rating.reset` are not working

```js
$(function() {
  $('#rating-id').rating();
  $('#rating-id').on('change', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.5/css/star-rating.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.5/js/star-rating.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input name="rating-id" type="text" id="rating-id" class="rating-kv" min=0 max=5 step=0.2 data-size="sm">
```